# Using juste in the right context

Tags: choix-de-mot, adverbes

In my French class, I said the phrase "J'ai juste une petite question" which my teacher corrected to "J'ai tout simplement une petite question" saying that *juste* is a bit of an anglicisme. I was wondering when it would be more appropriate to use *juste* instead of its alternatives like « ne...que » or « simplement »?

Comment: I know I'm not answering "when it would be more appropriate to use *juste*"  because I really can't see a better example than in *juste une petite question* which is a perfectly correct and common French phrase. Of course there are a lot of other uses of *juste* but I do think it ought to be another question altogether, and for a complete review of all its uses dictionaries can do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have said the exactly the same thing. « (*J'ai) juste une petite question* ».

**First** because it is the usual phrase in this case. Let's look at what people say on French forums.

[Juste une petite question](https://francebienvenue2.com/2020/10/10/juste-une-petite-question/) (un blog dont le but est de faire aimer le français)

> L : Maman. Maman !
> M : Oui ?
> L : Juste une petite question. Comment ils font, les hippopotames, pour se gratter ?
> P : Ils demandent à un autre hippopotame.
> L : D’accord.

[Juste une petite question](https://forums.futura-sciences.com/physique/302063-une-petite-question.html) ([Futura sciences](https://forums.futura-sciences.com/physique/302063-une-petite-question.html))

[Juste une petite question](https://www.ilephysique.net/sujet-juste-une-petite-question-17041.html) (Forum physique-chimie)

[Juste une petite question sur une toute petite traduction](https://www.prepa-hec.org/forum/juste-une-petite-question-sur-une-toute-petite-traduction-t7652.html) ? (Forum de prepa HEC<sup>1</sup>)

**Then** because it appears to be correct French in dictionaries.

[TLF. II. A. 4.](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/juste)

> [Avec une valeur restrictive] Exactement, mais pas plus; seulement, à peine.

[Le Robert](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/juste) gives *seulement* and  *rien que* as possible synonyms of the adverb *juste*.

The only dictionary I have found stating *juste* would be an Anglicism in that case is [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/juste#Adverbe) and I personally don't agree with it and I really think this should be corrected. The use of *juste* in that case, and especially in the phrase *juste une question* has long been established even in written matter as an [ngram can show us](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=juste%20une%20question&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cjuste%20une%20question%3B%2Cc0).

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Students in prepas HEC (higher education) are selected and usually have a very good level in French.</sup>

Comment: D'accord pour dire que c'est courant et établi aujourd'hui et que le professeur n'aurait jamais du reprendre l'OP, mais la popularité de *juste* avec ce sens (qui existait en français de manière plus ou moins rampante depuis un moment) a quand même été nettement boostée par l'anglais dans la deuxième partie du XXe siècle, peut être grâce à des chansons comme *I'm just a gigolo* et *I just called to say I love you...*

Comment: @jlliagre Tu crois que c'est vraiment l'anglais ? bouaf...   On trouve des exemples de *juste* dans ce sens dès le 19e s. De toutes façon *juste une question* c'est essentiellement de la langue orale, donc peu d'archives accessibles. Je l'entends dire en conversation depuis... toujours (on me le dit et je le dis). De même que « Je voudrais juste te/vous faire remarquer que... ».

Comment: Je suis d'accord avec None. Rien à voir avec l'anglais, et entendu depuis toujours.

Comment: @jlliagre — Il y a parfois un effet litote : « C'est juste un problème de vie ou de mort » — ou ironique « C'est juste une blessure égotique, [douloureuse pour lui], mais ça [n']empêchera pas le monde de tourner » — dérisoire « Mario ? juste une question métaphysique de l'intrication du jeu électronique dans le quotidien des quinquagénaires du troisième millénaire » — … ad libitum …

Comment: Personne n'a bien lu mon commentaire, j'ai l'impression...

Comment: @jlliagre Si si l'humour lyrique ne m'a pas échappé !